# SilverStripe DataObjects as Children

Tags: php, silverstripe

Assume a **HolderPage** with

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Articles' => 'Article'
);

public function Children() {
    return Article::get(); // Rather than $this->Articles(), for the sake of simplicity
}
```

The **Page.ss** in Templates folder doing its usual work:

```
<% loop $Menu(1) %>
<li">
    <a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a>
    <% if $Children %>
    <ul>
    <% loop $Children %>
        <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_if %>
</li>
```

The **Article** object has a `Link()` method that returns the right link.

The articles are not fetched under the *HolderPage* in the menu as children, whereas other parent pages with *normal* child pages (`Page` instances) are fetched and shown correctly.

**What is the correct way to define DataObjects as children in SS 3.4.1?**

Comment: You will need to put the Children function into the HolderPage class, not the HolderPage_Controller class. Also Children might be a reserved word, you can use something like ArticleList.

Comment: I'm unsure about your question. Can you please clarify?